# Libqmi - glib callback function not getting called

Tags: glib, libqmi

I am new to libqmi and wanted to start by just opening a new device. But the callback function is never getting called and therefore no device object returned.

I running the code on Ubuntu 64 Bit.

On this website: https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GAsyncResult.html

I found how this should be handled and programmed it that way, but it still doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libqmi-glib/libqmi-glib.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>

using namespace std;

void device_create_start(const char* device_file);
void device_create_stop(GObject* obj, GAsyncResult* res, gpointer data);

int something = 0;

int main()
{
    cout << "Start\n";
    device_create_start("/dev/cdc-wdm0");

    cout << "DEBUG: Something: " << something << "\n";
    cout << "Stop\n";

    return 0;
}

void device_create_start(const char* device_file)
{
    GFile* file = g_file_new_for_path(device_file);

    if(file)
    {
        GCancellable* cancellable = g_cancellable_new();
        GAsyncReadyCallback callback = device_create_stop;
        gpointer user_data = NULL;

        cout << "INFO: qmi_device_new starting!\n";
        qmi_device_new(file, cancellable, callback, user_data);
        cout << "INFO: qmi_device_new started!\n";

        cout <<  "INFO: Waiting!\n";
        usleep(10000);

        cout <<  "INFO: Is cancelled?: " << g_cancellable_is_cancelled(cancellable) << "\n";
        cout <<  "INFO: canceling!\n";
        g_cancellable_cancel(cancellable);
        cout <<  "INFO: Waiting again!\n";
        usleep(100000);
        cout <<  "INFO: Is cancelled?: " << g_cancellable_is_cancelled(cancellable) << "\n";

        something = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Could not create device file!\n";
    }
}
void device_create_stop(GObject* obj, GAsyncResult* res, gpointer data)
{
    cout << "INFO: device_create_stop\n";

    something = 2;

    cout << "INFO: qmi_device_new_finish starting\n";
    GError *error;
    QmiDevice* device = qmi_device_new_finish(res, &error);
    cout << "INFO: qmi_device_new_finish started\n";

    if(device == NULL)
    {
         cout << "ERROR: Could not create device!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "INFO: Device created!\n";
        //device_open(device);
    }
}
```

When I run this code the output is:

```
Start
INFO: qmi_device_new starting!
INFO: qmi_device_new started!
INFO: Waiting!
INFO: Is cancelled?: 0
INFO: canceling!
INFO: Waiting again!
INFO: Is cancelled?: 1
DEBUG: Something: 1
Stop
```

The code in the callback function is never called.

**Update 1**

I simplified the code and changed some things that I oversaw on the gnome reference site, like a static callback function. But this doesn't work either

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libqmi-glib/libqmi-glib.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>
#include <glib/gprintf.h>

using namespace std;

void device_create_start(const char* device_file);
static void device_create_stop(GObject* obj, GAsyncResult* res, gpointer data);

int something = 0;

int main()
{
    g_printf ("Start\n");
    device_create_start("/dev/cdc-wdm0");

    cout << "DEBUG: Something: " << something << "\n";

    while(true)
    {
        ;
    }

    cout << "Stop\n";

    return 0;
}
void device_create_start(const char* device_file)
{
    GFile* file = g_file_new_for_path(device_file);

    if(file)
    {
        cout << "INFO: qmi_device_new starting!\n";
        qmi_device_new(file, NULL, device_create_stop, NULL);
        cout << "INFO: qmi_device_new started!\n";
        something = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Could not create device!\n";
    }
}
static void device_create_stop(GObject* obj, GAsyncResult* res, gpointer data)
{
    g_printf ("Hurray!\n");
    something = 2;
}
```

The new output:

```
Start
INFO: qmi_device_new starting!
INFO: qmi_device_new started!
DEBUG: Something: 1
```

Does anyone has a clue why this is not working?

Comment: Run a main loop.

Comment: @PhilipWithnall That didn't work

Comment: @PhilipWithnall You were right. I just had to look more into G Lib

Here a Link for people who have the same Problem: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html

Answer (score 1):

As Philip said (hey Philip!), you're missing the main loop. The `qmi_device_new()` function is an method that finishes asynchronously, and once finished, the result of the operation is provided in the `callback` function you provide. In order for the asynchronous function to even do something, you need to have a GMainLoop running for as long as your program logic runs.